# JavaFX replace AJAX?

Tags: ajax, javafx

Can JavaFX replace what AJAX do? i went through a couple of articles like this http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/ajax_vs_javafx.php. But I am still confused. anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will happen, certainly not at the moment. JavaFX depends on java, there's very little support cross-platform (windows mobile does work but it's very limited). There was talk about set top boxes coming out to run javafx but it doesn't seem to have taken off :\ It's a real shame, in many ways I really like JavaFX. It's a shame they won't [open the source](http://steveonjava.com/javafx-petition/). Also for deployment there is a dependancy on a sun server to get some jars (not possible to host on your own server), so when it goes down (and it is a when) then everyones apps stop working!

Javascript keeps my vote unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes JavaFX can do everything that AJAX can do and more - on a supported platform. Unfortunately JavaFX isn't supported on most smartphones so you won't get the same reach as AJAX. You also need a browser plugin which you don't need for AJAX.

But if these limitations aren't a problem, then I think you will have less misery using JavaFX instead of AJAX.